# first list gets auto updated aftter appending another second list to it and then changing the second list in Python

Tags: python, list

please take a look at this code

```
a = [int(x) for x in bin(2)[2:]]
coordinates = []
sum = [1,3]
for x in a:
    if x == 1:
        coordinates.append(sum)
    m = ((3*(sum[0]**2)+A) * libnum.invmod(2*sum[1],p)) % p
    x3 = (m**2 - 2*sum[0]) % p
    sum[1] = ((m*(sum[0]-x3) - sum[1]) + p) % p
    sum[0] = x3
```

my sum list gets updated in the loop and the new values should be added to the coordinates list if they match the conditions. the problem is that after appending the sum list to the coordinates list whenever the values change in sum they also change in coordinates. there is some kind of link between them. Can you please help me with this problem? How can I unlink them so that just the values are appended and stay fixed.

Comment: Don't call your variable `sum`, because it clobbers the builtin `sum` function.  Use `.copy()` if you want to insert a new copy of the list rather than a reference to it (which will update when the original does).

Comment: @Samwise .copy() fixed my problem. If you put as an answer I can close this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you assign a list value to a new variable, it only stores the reference number, when you append this variable to a new list, the same reference number is being used. So when you later change the value, it changes the values of the list defined by that reference number, hence changing what that variable stores wherever it was used.

e.g

```
coordinates = []
some = [1,3] # avoid using 'sum' as variable name as it is a built in function
coordinates.append(some)

print("coordinates initially:", coordinates)

some.append("interesting")
print("coordinates after chaning 'some':", coordinates)
```

**Output**:

```
coordinates initially: [[1, 3]]
coordinates after chaning 'some': [[1, 3, 'interesting']]
```

This doenst make sense for small lists but when you consider that lists can hold huge amounts of values, it makes it much faster to use reference numbers

Thus, the solution is that we need to infact append a copy of the some list and not just the reference number.

For this, we can do the following:

```
import copy

# We can use the copy.deepcopy() function and pass it the list we need copied
coordinates.append(copy.deepcopy(some))
```

Comment: `.copy()` also works as @Samwise commented

Comment: Using `some.copy` Is enough here — no need for `deepcopy` since the elements of `some` are immutable (and more specifically because this program doesn't modify elements of `some` in place).

Comment: @MatthiasFripp What exactly do you mean that `some` is not mutable? it is a list which is a mutable data type. And from what i see, the program does change the elements of `some`  in the last two lines. (Unless i misunderstand what you mean)

Comment: `some` is mutable, but its elements are `int`s which are immutable.  If `some` were a list of lists `deepcopy` would make sense.

Comment: Oh i see now, thank you i dint know that differenct

Comment: `some.copy()` would also be enough even if the elements of `some` were mutable, e.g. lists, provided the code doesn't modify the elements themselves. `some.copy()` is necessary and sufficient if the code adds, removes or replaces elements in `some`. But if the code added or removed elements in sublists in `some`, _then_ you would need to `deepcopy` `some` at the start.